# Find all data points within an hour

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel table that has data about times people were active.  I have the start time and the end time.  What I want to know is how many people were active during each hour across all days in the table. Not each day each hour, just each hour, basically to see which hour is the most used

My data has:

```
05/24/2015 18:00    05/24/2015 18:00
05/24/2015 18:00    05/24/2015 18:00
05/24/2015 18:01    05/24/2015 18:01
05/24/2015 18:01    05/24/2015 18:01
05/25/2015 18:02    05/25/2015 18:27
05/24/2015 19:00    05/24/2015 19:01
05/24/2015 20:19    05/24/2015 20:19
05/24/2015 21:00    05/24/2015 21:00
05/26/2015 21:00    05/26/2015 21:00
05/27/2015 21:00    05/27/2015 23:01
```

Some of the data is very short while others are very long.  So from above we can say:

```
18:00 - 5
19:00 - 1
20:00 - 1
21:00 - 3
22:00 - 1
23:00 - 1
```

As you can see from the last entry, it spans three hours and should be counted accordingly.

Is there a way to be able to do this through a PivotTable, or some other function?

update: update the data so the end date is after the first part. Also the data is in 2 columns not 4.

Comment: You can perform a simple cropping to the non-integer part (separate column) but I'm pretty sure there's a built-in option for dates with Pivots, instead of years you just choose hours.

Comment: Some of your start times are after the end times, and some pairs span multiple days?

Comment: If a time span covers (eg) two days then each hour time slot should be counted twice ?

Comment: I've updated the data so that it reflects what my actual data looks like.  The start is always before the end and the data doesn't go beyond  24 hours.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @pnuts Their activity was under 1 minute.  The seconds are not important for what I'm counting, at least from my view point.

Comment: I wonder what happened there.  I was sure that was 1 when I entered the question.  I've fixed to show 1 for 22:00

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

One way, without array formula/e, is to create a matrix and sum the values. For this first split the date/times into separate columns for date and time (eg with Text to Columns). Then add a row (eg Row1) with the start of each hour, including the start of the next day.

A formula such as:

```
=IF(AND($B2>=F$1,$B2<G$1),1,0)+IF(AND($D2>E$1,G$1>$B2+1/24,HOUR($B2)<>HOUR($D2)),1,0)
```

in F1 in the example, copied across and down to suit.

Sum with something like:

```
=IF(SUM(F2:F11)=0,"",SUM(F2:F11))
```

in F12 in the example, and copied across to suit.

[image: SO30562881 example]

I hope there *is* a PT solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to deal with some times; specifically values like *19:00* that resolves as *0.791666666666667* or *23:00* that resolves to *0.958333333333333*. You will also have to add exactly an hour to the times in order that you can reference the upper limit.

1. To add an hour, use the [TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457). This easily allows you to add an hour (e.g. `TIME(1, 0, 0)`) or even an hour minus a second (e.g. `TIME(1, 0, -1)`).
2. Round everything off to the nearest second with the [MROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mround-function-2f10722d-38ef-4197-be12-a3f02212e637). This function allows you to specify the increment to round off to and we will use an interval of TIME(0, 0, 1) or one second.

   [image: Time Counted by the hour]

The formula in E3 is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((MROUND(MOD(A$2:A$11, 1), TIME(0, 0, 1))>=MROUND(D3, TIME(0, 0, 1)))*(MROUND(MOD(B$2:B$11, 1), TIME(0, 0, 1))<MROUND(D3+TIME(1, 0, 0), TIME(0, 0, 1)))+(MROUND(MOD(A$2:A$11,1),TIME(0,0,1))<=MROUND(D3,TIME(0,0,1)))*(MROUND(MOD(B$2:B$11,1),TIME(0,0,1))>=MROUND(D3, TIME(0,0,1)))))
```

Since this is actually a form of `OR` where it is possible that both conditions could be true, I've used the [SIGN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SIGN-function-109C932D-FCDC-4023-91F1-2DD0E916A1D8) to determine whether to count the entry or not. I've used `=TIME(ROW(18:18), 0, 0)` in D3. Fill down as necessary.

If there are some oddball data entries that seem to produce bad counts, append your sample data in the original question and I'll try to address the anomalies.

I don't know how many rows you have to reference but I would advise keeping the referenced cell ranges to a minimum and *never* full column references.